# What does this Ruby line say?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operator-keyword

I am working with a custom renderer, and I used some copy paste from another site. I can't seem to figure out what this piece is doing right here.

```
"#{options[:callback]}(#{data})"
```

Here is the piece of code in full context.

```
  ActionController.add_renderer :as3 do |data, options|
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(data) unless data.respond_to?(:to_str)
    data = "#{options[:callback]}(#{data})" unless options[:callback].blank?
    self.content_type ||= Mime::JSON
    self.response_body = data
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple string interpolation. It will produce a string like this, where `callback` is the value of `options[:callback]`, and `value` is whatever is in the variable `data`.

```
"callback(value)"
```

In Ruby, double-quoted strings support interpolation via `#{}` syntax. That is, if you have a variable `x` containing the value `3`, the string `"The value of x is #{x}"` will be evaluated to `"The value of x is 3"`. Inside a `#{}` you can have any arbitrarily complex Ruby expression, including array/hash indexing. So, the first part of the string, `"#{options[:callback]}"` is simply substituting the value of `options[:callback]` into the string.

The next part, the `()` is simply raw string data, not executable code. Inside the `()`, you have a second `#{}` substitution of `data`. It might be clearer if you replace the two variable substituions with `x` and `y`:

```
 x = 3
 y = 4
 "#{ x }(#{ y })"
```

The above will evaluate to the string `"3(4)"`

Answer (score 1):

This is converting a JSON response to JSONP; imagine `data` is:

```
'{"some": "thing", "goes": "here"}'
```

JSONP states that the data should be wrapped in a JavaScript function call. So of `options[:callback]` is the string `test` (the name of the function to call), the resulting JSONP would be:

```
'test({"some": "thing", "goes": "here"})'
```

Comment: No, the #{} notation is string interpolation.

Comment: Right--I suppose to be technically correct I should have wrapped the lines in quotes. I also suspect that I misunderstood the question as "what is the purpose of this code," not literally "what is it doing." :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a template that replaces the first field with the value of options poiinted to by the interned string `:callback`, and the second field, inside the parens with the contents of `data`.

I'd bet a buck that the resulting string is going to be eval'd somewhere else, where it will become a call to a procedure.  That would work something like this:

```
options[:callback] = "foo"
data="arg,arg,arg"
```

(Notice that data is being encoded into JSON, so the *string* passed as data is a json string.

The string then turns into "foo(arg.arg.arg)", and when it's eval'd it becomes a call to routine `foo` with those arguments.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

**Update:**

Actually, I take it back about the Ruby eval -- although that would work, it's more likely turning into a Javascript function call.  This would then let you pass the name of a javascript function as a string and the code would return the appropriate callback function for execution by javascript later.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite

```
"#{options[:callback]}(#{data})"
```

as

```
options[:callback].to_s + "(" + data.to_s + ")"
```